# PHPExcel HTML writer: how to alter the default css?

Tags: php, css, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to write excel files from mysql. I wabt also this data to be available as HTML. I found there's an HTML writer in PHPExcel, but I have problems with its css (for example, it does npot put in the table columns left/right borders).

Is there an easy way to alter the css of the HTML?

Comment: There is no method to change the default css, the easiest approach is probably to create your own version of the HTML Writer

Comment: That's what i thought. Thanks! (@MarkBaker put it as an answer and I'll accept it)